# how can i track my mobile app user when the app is killed

Tags: node.js, react-native

i want to implement tracking in my app but i am confused on how to get the location from the app if the app is not opened and send it to the server i tried socket , GPS-tracking but it did not work.
can any one guide me to how this is implemented and any resources or libraries to use  ?

Answer (score 1):

For Android projects React Native includes [headless JS](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android) that does just what you are asking.

iOS is more complicated but the best solution I've found is a package called [React Native Background Geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-background-geolocation)

Comment: did you know how to connect the backend with the frontend with any listener eg. sockets when the app is killed to keep track of the location of the user.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible in a PWA without a plugin due to W3C's and Jake Archibald's refusal to implement the TravelManager detailed [here](https://github.com/RichardMaher/Brotkrumen)

If the TravelManager were to be implemented a ServiceWorker intance would be automatically spun up on change of location in order to foreground your Web App or instantiate a new instance.